# Odoo14 - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cache'" while evaluating

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I have a model in Odoo to register some `logs(Log)` and a helper `class(Helper)` with async function to receive some data ad register on Log, this _job_function is called by a Cron Job like this:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    _name = 'saas.autobackup'
    _description = 'Description'

    field1 = fields.Char()
    field2 = fields.Char()
    field3 = fields.Datetime()

  def _job_function(self):
     helper = Hekper(self, ...) #Function receive self(Log) as parameter
     helper.run()  #call functions
```

This is the helper class:

```
class Helper():
  def __init__(self, og_obj)
    self.log_obj = log_obj  #Receive the Log object as parameter
 
  async def some_async_func(self):
   (...) #Some async functions to get val1 and val2
   self.create_log(val1,val2)
      
  def create_log(self, val1, val2)
    vals = {'field1': val1, 'field2': val1, 'field3': '2021-01-01'}
    self.log_obj.create(values)

  def run(self):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(self.some_async_func())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

For debugging propuser i have override the create class, to check if i'm sending wrong data.
When the job is executed and the create_log function is called, the program correctly enters the create function, I also checked the data sent in create, and I verified that they were correct, just like the one I keep when trying to create within the Odoo interface itself. the "create" button. But inside Odoo by the create button, create normally and by the create_log function I get this error:

```
ValueError: <class 'AttributeError'>: "'tuple' object has no attribute 'cache'" while evaluating
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a threading problem, you need to make sure to create a new cursor.

````
    def create_log(self, val1, val2)
        vals = {'field1': val1, 'field2': val1, 'field3': '2021-01-01'}
        with api.Environment.manage():
            with registry(self.env.cr.dbname).cursor() as new_cr:
                new_env = api.Environment(new_cr, self.env.uid, self.env.context)
                self.with_env(new_env).log_obj.create(values)```
````